# Pivot without aggregate to list all contents non character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have

| **ab** | **cd** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 8 | c |

I want

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| NULL | 3 | NULL |

I tried

```
select a, b, c
from aib
pivot
(
    max(ab)
    for cd in (a,b,c)
) k
```

but I am not able to list all the values as aggregate function is a must for pivot function

Comment: At a minimum, you need to describe what you want, not just give a cryptic example.

Comment: How you determine the column names? why it's not a,b or a,b,c,d?

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to differentiate your result rows by, a row number seems to do the trick.

```
declare @aib table (ab int, cd varchar(1));

insert into @aib (ab, cd)
values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'b'),
(8,'c');

with cte as (
  select *
    , row_number() over (partition by cd order by ab) rn
  from @aib
)
select a, b, c --, rn
from cte
pivot (
  max(ab) for cd in (a,b,c)
) k;
```

Note: If you add the DDL+DML for your sample data to future questions it makes it much easier to assist.